# how to add clipboard option to action_send intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-view

Somehow I've seen an application that can add Clipboard option to share options.

Something like this [screenshot](http://imm.io/15cxv)

How can I do that?

I tried to add extra intent, but the additional intent didn't show up

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra Text");
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    Intent clipboardIntent = new Intent();
    clipboardIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra Text");
    clipboardIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chooser Title");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { clipboardIntent });
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Thank you :D

Comment: have you got that done? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText("Text to copy");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Extra Text"+clipboard.getText());
intent.setType("text/plain");



Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chooser Title");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] { clipboardIntent });
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: the clipbaord has to be installed for this .share intent shows all the apps which have  intent filter  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: Thanks... But I've tried that. The problem is as long as the application is installed the clipboard selection will still showed up even if the application is closed. I've tried to create the intent filter programmatically so I can unregister the receiver, but the selection won't show up.